# Need clarity on "padding" parameter in Bert Tokenizer

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I have been fine-tuning a **BERT** model for sentence classification. In training, while tokenization I had passed these parameters `padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=150` but while inferencing it is still predicting even if `padding="max_length"` parameter is not being passed.

Surprisingly, predictions are the same in both cases when `padding="max_length"` is passed or not but if `padding="max_length"` is not being passed, inferencing is much faster.

So, I need some clarity on the parameter "padding" in Bert Tokenizer. Can someone help me to understand how best is able to predict even without the padding since the length of the sentences will differ and does it have any negative consequences If `padding="max_length"` is not passed while inferencing? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When passing a list of sentences to a tokenizer, each sentence might have a different length. Hence the output of the tokenizer for each sentence will have a different length. Padding is a strategy for ensuring tensors are rectangular by adding a special padding token to shorter sentences.

Consider the following example where `padding="max_length", max_length=10`.

```
batch_sentences = ["Hello World", "Hugging Face Library"]
encoded_input = tokenizer(batch_sentences, padding="max_length", max_length=10)
print(encoded_input)

{'input_ids': [[101, 8667, 1291, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [101, 20164, 10932, 10289, 3371, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 'token_type_ids': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]}
```

Notice that the output of the tokenizer for each sentence is padded to the `maximum_length` which is 10 by a special padding token '0'. Similarly, if we set `padding=True`, the output of the tokenizer for each sentence will be padded to the length of the longest sequence in the batch.

Coming back to your question, padding has no effect if you pass a list of just one sentence to the tokenizer. If you have set `batch_size = 1` during training or inference, your model will be processing your data one sentence at a time. This could be one reason why padding is not making a difference in your case.

Another possible yet very unlikely reason padding does not make a difference in your case is that all your sentences have the same length. Lastly, if you have not converted the output of the tokenizer to a PyTorch or TensorFlow tensor, having varying sentence lengths would not be a problem. This again is unlikely in your case given that you used your model for training and testing.

Comment: Just to answer your question my training batch_size was 8 and still it didn't throw any error on not giving the parameter padding="max_length" and the sentences were of different length too.

Comment: Could you share your code? It is hard to pass a concrete judgment on the issue you are facing without looking at the code.